# How do I use GROUP_CONCAT and get multiple results with joins

Tags: mysql, distinct

I'm using this mysql query to pull back a single result, and concatenate the results from a join:

```
SELECT card_name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat_name SEPARATOR ',') AS catcsv 
FROM  `cards` 
LEFT JOIN card2cat ON cards.cards_id = card2cat.card2cat_card 
LEFT JOIN cats ON card2cat.card2cat_cat = cats.cats_id 
WHERE  `card_id` = 1
```

This returns:

```
card_name    catcsv
-----------------------------
Violets      Floral, Occasion
```

This is perfect for what I need... however I need to get the same results, but for multiple results like so:

```
SELECT card_name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat_name SEPARATOR ',') AS catcsv 
FROM  `cards` 
LEFT JOIN card2cat ON cards.cards_id = card2cat.card2cat_card 
LEFT JOIN cats ON card2cat.card2cat_cat = cats.cats_id 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

..but that returns this:

```
card_name    catcsv
-----------------------------
Violets      Floral, Occasion, Birthday, Down at the Farm, Cats and Dogs, Down at the Yard, Humour, Beach, Coast and Harbour, Gardening
```

i.e ALL the possible cats :( I've tried removing DISTINCT and it's even worse and returns every category multiple times!

The structure/names I've used above are simplified for posting, so pasting a DB structure dump here isn't too practical, I hope I've explained it well enough!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT card_name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat_name SEPARATOR ',') AS catcsv 
FROM  `cards` 
LEFT JOIN card2cat ON cards.cards_id = card2cat.card2cat_card 
LEFT JOIN cats ON card2cat.card2cat_cat = cats.cats_id 
GROUP BY card_name
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: You DUDE! Perfect. I can't get my head around why that works, as it looked like it was already grouping by catcsv but it does. Good man sir!